# How to get an Android "bound" service to survive a configuration restart

Tags: java, android

I have an android app with some global state (including some large `SoundPool`s) that requires clean up, so following answers to my previous question I'm attempting to handle this using a `Service`.

I'm currently using a *bound* service that every activity binds/unbinds to in `onStart`/`onStop`, and when all activities stop the service becomes unbound and `onDestroy` called on the service, letting me release the `SoundPools`.

Since the activity lifecycle deliberately overlaps (the new activity `onStart` fires before the old one fires `onStop`), when navigating between activities there is always at least one activity bound, and the service stays alive.

However, if I rotate the screen to cause a configuration restart, the service is unbound and dies when the active activity goes through the configuration restart lifecycle.

How can I get around this and keep the service alive across restarts, whilst still allowing the service to die when the application is stopped?

Comment: I'll have to work more on this sometime. I avoid binding like the plague, so I do not have a ready pattern that can address your issue, and apparently the advice that I gave you before was flawed.

Comment: How about adding some bind/unbind functionality to my `Application` instance - increment/decrement an internal counter and only actually bind/unbind once?

Comment: It's possible that would work, though it's a bit risky (e.g., unhandled exceptions causing you to fail to decrement).

Comment: Another approach would be to use a "started" `Service` which can decide when it needs to shutdown itself. Then I can replicate binding/unbinding from activities, shutting down on the last unbind, but having a method the activities can call to flag a configuration restart is happening?

Comment: How about handling rotations without restarting activity?

Answer (score 19):

Ok, since this has proven to be an especially difficult question, I thought I'd post my solution here in case anyone ever hits anything similar.

There are clearly several ways to approach this, but the simplest I've used is to have a "started" service that decides when to shut itself down. My activities each bind/unbind to the service, and after a set time delay (I've used 1 minute) the service will shut itself down if no further activities have bound - this covers if the user stops using the app plus if there are any fatal activity errors.

The shutdown timer is scheduled within `onUnbind()` and gets cancelled in `onStartCommand()`, `onBind()`, `onRebind()`. If it fires, it shuts the service down cleanly, which in turn triggers a clean up of the managed state in the service's `onDestroy()`.

My `Service` code is as follows:

```
public class LocalStateService extends Service {

    /** The binder to give to clients. */
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalStateBinder();

    /** Used for time-delayed shutdown. */
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    /**
     * Called before starting or the first binding.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // initialise state...
    }

    /**
     * Called when this service is explicitly started.
     * @param intent    The intent passed on starting, unused
     * @param flags     Startup flags, unused
     * @param startId   Identifies each start request 
     * @return Desired restart behaviour
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        cancelShutdown();

        // if killed, we would like Android to restart this service, but don't bother re-delivering
        // the original intent used to start the service
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the first client binds.
     * @param intent        The intent passed on binding
     * @return The binding to use
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        cancelShutdown();
        return binder;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the first of previous clients re-binds.
     * @param intent        The intent passed on binding
     */
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        cancelShutdown();
    }

    /**
     * Called when all clients have unbound.
     * @param intent        The first intent originally passed on binding
     * @return Whether this service should be notified of rebinding
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // post a callback to be run in 1 minute
        handler.postDelayed(delayedShutdown, 1000L * 60);

        // we do want onRebind called when clients return
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // state cleanup...
    }

    private Runnable delayedShutdown = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            LocalStateService.this.stopSelf();
        }

    };

    /**
     * Cancel any shutdown timer that may have been set.
     */
    private void cancelShutdown() {
        // remove any shutdown callbacks registered
        handler.removeCallbacks(delayedShutdown);
    }
}
```

Instead of doing this from my `Application`, my main activity calls `startService(..)` in `onCreate()` since this will work both for initial startup and when the user goes back to using a paused app (where the service may or may not have decided to shut itself down).

Each activity then binds and unbinds as per normal.

I found that:

- When navigating between activities, no service callback gets fired. Since the activity lifecycle overlaps, these are secondary bind/unbinds
- When an activity restarts (e.g. screen rotation), the service gets an `onUnbind()` then an `onRebind()` call
- When pausing the app (e.g. press home from main activity) or when finishing (e.g. press back from main activity), the service gets `onUnbind()` then the timer fires.

Comment: Did you consider calling startService(yourself) from within onBind()?

Comment: Why call cancelShutdown in onBind? How could a shutdown have been scheduled before the first Activity binds to the service?

Comment: @JoeBowbeer - because more than one activity can bind to the service. A second activity will enter using the onBind function.

Comment: @ScottNaef - onBind and onUnbind are both only called once right? Otherwise this delayed shutdown scheme wouldn't work.

Comment: @Joe Bowbeer - That is true for each activity/fragment binding to the service.  Because multiple fragments could bind to the service, bind and unbind may be called many times in the same activity context.

Comment: @ScottNaef - I'm not seeing this in practice. To clarify, I'm referring to the calls to onBind/unUnbind/UnRebind in the Service snippet above running in a single process with multiple Contexts binding using a single intent. onBind is called the first time and not called again unless the last client unbinds (onUnbind).

Comment: Sweet! I was actually considering using a started service and pinging it periodically from the various activities/fragments that were interested in it but this works even better. My use case is to keep a shared bluetooth connection across activities that should survive configuration changes.

Comment: Another point: When swiping to close the app, the service was restarted (because it was sticky) however it would continue to run despite no activities being bound. My solution to this was to schedule the shutdown from the `onStartCommand` callback. Now, the service requires binding, but does not auto-destroy immediately when all clients are unbound.